# Interpolation is LESS variables

Tags: php, css, less

In PHP, you can do the following.

```
$a = 'b';
$b = 'c';

echo $$a;
```

Resulting in

```
c
```

Can I do this in LESS?

```
@Red: #FF0000;
@Color: "Red";

div {
    color: @@Color;
}
```

The basis of this idea is that on my application you can change the color scheme, and when it's changed I was planning to execute this:

```
less.modifyVars({
  '@Color': 'blue'
});
```

If there is a better way to do this, I'd appreciate an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax for that:

```
color: ~"@{@{Color}}";
```

Here is a working example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxxpOp

Or a simpler version using referencing variables (thanks to @seven-phases-max):

```
color: @@Color;
```

Comment: Awful, use ["referencing variables"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names) instead.

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks for the comment. Updated the answer based on that :)